# Limited sequence limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given limited sequence $x_{n}$, that $x_{n+2} \leq \frac{x_{n} + x_{n+1}}{2}$.
Prove that sequence $y_{n} = max\{x_{n}, x_{n+1}\}$ have a limit.

Comment: Verify that $\{y_n\}$ is decreasing.

Comment: Following up with Kavi Rama Murthy's comment, observe that if $x_n\le x_{n+1}$, $y_n=y_{n+1}$ whereas if $x_n> x_{n+1}$, $y_{n+1}<y_{n}$.

Comment: @GReyes, so after that we should prove that $x_{n}$ have a limit?

Comment: Bounded monotonic sequences always have a limit. You can just refer to that theorem.

Comment: @GReyes, thank you. But in this case if we have bounded $n_{n}$ it does not matter there is the limit for it or not?

Comment: You are looking at $y_n$, not at $x_n$,  and you know two facts: $a)$ $y_n$ is non-increasing and $b)$ $y_n$ is bounded, since $x_n$ is bounded. Therefore, by the theorem, $y_n$ has a limit.